# Contravariance for templated callback parameter like in C#

Tags: c++, contravariance

### The set-up

Consider two types, one of which inherits from the other:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class shape {  };
class circle : Shape {  };
```

And two functions which accept an object of that type, respectively:

```cpp
void shape_func(const shape& s) { std::cout << "shape_func called!\n"; }
void circle_func(const circle& c) { std::cout << "circle_func called!\n"; }
```

### The function template

Now I want a function template, to which I can pass:

1. An object of one of those types *(or others like it)*.
2. A pointer to one of those functions *(or others like it)* that is compatible with the passed object.

The following is my attempt at declaring this function template:

```cpp
template<class T>
void call_twice(const T& obj, void(*func)(const T&))
{
    func(obj);
    func(obj);
}
```

<sup>(In practice its body would do something more useful, but for demonstration purpose I simply let it call the passed function with the passed object twice.)</sup>

### Observed behavior

```cpp
int main() {
    shape s;
    circle c;

    call_twice<shape>(s, &shape_func);   // works fine
    call_twice<circle>(c, &circle_func); // works fine
    //call_twice<circle>(c, &shape_func);  // compiler error if uncommented
}
```

### Expected behavior

I was hoping that the third call would also work.

After all, since `shape_func` accepts any `shape`, it also accepts a `circle` — so by substituting `circle` for `T` it should be possible for the compiler to resolve the function template without conflicts.

In fact, this is how the corresponding generic function behaves in C#:

```cpp
// C# code
static void call_twice<T>(T obj, Action<T> func) { ... }
```

It can be called as `call_twice(c, shape_func)` without problem because, to say it in C# lingo, the type parameter `T` of `Action<T>` is [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

### Question

Is this possible in C++?

That is, how would the function template `call_twice` have to be implemented in order to accept all three of the calls in this example?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you mean [something like this?](https://ideone.com/vOn0Wh)

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, that's the behavior I intended! Thanks! Can you post it as an answer and explain it a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), best shown by example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Shape {};
struct Circle : public Shape {};

template<class Bp, class Dp>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Bp,Dp>::value,void>
call_fn(Dp const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Bp&))
{
    pfn(obj);
}

void shape_func(const Shape& s) { std::cout << "shape_func called!\n"; }
void circle_func(const Circle& s) { std::cout << "circle_func called!\n"; }

int main()
{
    Shape shape;
    Circle circle;

    call_fn(shape, shape_func);
    call_fn(circle, circle_func);
    call_fn(circle, shape_func);
}
```

**Output**

```
shape_func called!
circle_func called!
shape_func called!
```

**How It Works**

This implementation uses a simple (perhaps too much so) exercise utilizing [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) in conjunction with [`std::is_base_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of) to provide qualified overload resolution with potentially two different types (one of the object, the other of the provide function's argument list). Specifically, this:

```
template<class Bp, class Dp>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Bp,Dp>::value,void>
call_fn(Dp const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Bp&))
```

says that this function template requires two template arguments. If they're either the same type OR `Bp` is somehow a base of `Dp`, then provide a type (in this case `void`). We then use that type as the result type of our function. Therefore, for the first invocation, the resulting instantiation looks like this after deduction:

```
void call_fn(Shape const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Shape&))
```

which was what we desired. A similar instantiation results from the second invocation:

```
void call_fn(Circle const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Circle&))
```

The third instantiation will produce this:

```
void call_fn(Circle const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Shape&))
```

because `Dp` and `Bp` are different, but `Dp` is a derivative.

---

**Failure Case**

To see this fail (as we want it to do so), modify the code with non-related types. Simply remove `Shape` from the base-class inheritance list of `Circle`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Shape {};
struct Circle {};

template<class Bp, class Dp>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Bp,Dp>::value,void>
call_fn(Dp const& obj, void (*pfn)(const Bp&))
{
    pfn(obj);
}

void shape_func(const Shape& s) { std::cout << "shape_func called!\n"; }
void circle_func(const Circle& s) { std::cout << "circle_func called!\n"; }

int main()
{
    Shape shape;
    Circle circle;

    call_fn(shape, shape_func);   // still ok.
    call_fn(circle, circle_func); // still ok.
    call_fn(circle, shape_func);  // not OK. no overload available, 
                                  // since a Circle is not a Shape.
}
```

The result would be no-matching function call for the third invoke.